# Конструирование объкта производного класса при множественном ("ромбовидном") наследовании в C++

Tags: c++

Возник вопрос по теме множественного наследования в C++. Допустим, у нас есть некоторый код, представляющий собой случай *«ромбовидного»* наследования, в котором класс A является виртуальным базовым классом для классов **B** и **С**, которые, в свою очередь, являются базовыми для класса **D**:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int a;
public:
    A() : a(0) {}
    A(int _a) : a(_a) {}

};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    int b;
public:
    B(int _a, int _b) : A(_a), b(_b) {}
};

class C : virtual public A {
public:
    int c;
public:
    C(int _a, int _c) : A(_a), c(_c) {}
};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    int d;
public:
    D(int _a, int _b, int _c, int _d) : B(_a, _b), C(_a, _c), d(_d) {}
};

int main() {

    D obj(1, 2, 3, 4);

    std::cout << "obj.a = " << obj.a << std::endl; // Выводит: 0
    std::cout << "obj.b = " << obj.b << std::endl; // Выводит: 2
    std::cout << "obj.c = " << obj.c << std::endl; // Выводит: 3
    std::cout << "obj.d = " << obj.d << std::endl; // Выводит: 4

    return 0;
}
```

Ясно, что наличие виртуального базового класса **А** гарантирует, что при конструировании объекта типа **D** мы будем иметь только одну копию подобъекта класса **А**. Это приводит к совсем другому поведению, отличному от того, если бы базовый класс был не виртуальным. По результатам выполненного кода видно, что за создание этого единственного экземпляра подобъета класса **А**, отвечает конструктор по-умолчанию в классе **A**, причем его вызов происходит в конструкторе класса **D** посредством списка инициализации, а не в непосредсвенных потомках **B** и **С**, которые напрямую наследуют от **А**. Ясно, что вместо генерирования компилятором вывоза конструктора по-умолчанию можно явно указать вызов любого другого конструктора класса **A** в списке инициализации конструктора класса **D**.

**Вопрос в следующем:** вызывая конструкторы `B(_a, _b)` и  `C(_a, _c)` непосредственных классов-предков класса **D**, мы должны по цепочке прийти к явному вызову конструктора класса **A** в списках инициализации класса **B** и класса **C**, но этого не происходит при наличии виртуального базового класса. Получается *код инициализации `A(_a)` в конструкторах **B** и **C** классов просто игнорируется компилятором* и его можно безболезненно убрать, не меняя поведения?

Comment: Убрать-то можно, но не испортит ли это поведение в других случаях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать можно, на насколько это будет безболезненно в вашем абстрактном случае сказать не реально.

И к слову говоря, у вас класс `A` не является виртуальным, так как в нём нет виртуальных членов функций и указателя `_vptr` на `vtable` и т.д. и т.п.

По причине виртуального наследования классов `B` и `C` от `A`, класс `D` напрямую наследует `A`, а не через `B` и `С` для избежания одинаковых копий объекта `А` в `D` - поэтому если явно вызвать параметризированный конструктор `А` в `D` у вас потом выведется 1, 2, 3, 4.

Тоесть виртуальное наследование гарантирует прямое наследование без промежуточных предков, что в свою очередь обеспечивает только одну копию предка в наследнике.

Comment: А разве виртуальные члены-функции и виртуальные классы - не разные понятия? Мне кажется, что виртуальность класса определяет, каким образом будет сконструирован объект базового класса в составе объекта производного класса. И это не имеет значение, присутствуют ли в базовом классе виртуальные функции. Это независимые друг от друга вещи. Или все-таки не так?

Comment: вам необходимо концептуально разобраться в вопросе, а не размусоливать какие - то абстрактные вещи )